# Porque me ocasiona error

Tags: python

```
#Conversor de dolares
import math
opciones=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
while True:
    print(''' 
    Esto es un conversor de dolar 
    1.convertir dolar=>Euro
    2.convertir dolar=>Pesos colombianos
    3.convertir dolar=>Soles peruanos
    4.convertir dolar=>Libra esterlina
    5.convertir dolar=>Yenes
    6.Salir
    ''')
    opcion=input('Introducir opcion: ')
    if not(opcion in opciones):
        print('No seleccione ninguna opcion valida')
        input('pulse para continuar')
        continue
    if opcion=='1':
            try:
                dolar=float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
                Euro= dolar * 0.85
        print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Euro")
                input('Pulse para continuar')
            except:
                    print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
                    continue
    if opcion=='2':
            try:    
                    dolar=float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
                Euro= dolar * 3715.01
        print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Pesos colombianos")
                input('Pulse para continuar')
            except:
                    print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
                    continue
    if opcion=='3':
            try:
                    dolar=float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
                Euro= dolar * 3.55
        print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Soles peruanos")
                input('Pulse para continuar')
            except:
                    print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
                    continue
    if opcion=='4':
            try:
                    dolar=float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
                Euro= dolar * 0.75
        print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Libra esterlina")
                input('Pulse para continuar')
            except:
                    print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
                    continue
    if opcion=='5':
            try:
                    dolar=float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
                Euro= dolar * 0.0094
        print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Yenes")
                input('Pulse para continuar')
            except:
                    print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
                    continue
```

Comment: ¿Qué error? ¿Dónde? Sé un poco más explícita por favor! En python la indentación es MUY importante, PERO QUE MUY IMPORTANTE, en serio. No hay otra manera de definir bloques de código! Así que si tienes 8 espacios en una línea, 12 en la siguiente y 8 en la otra de nuevo... va a volverse loco intentando encontrar la lógica! Usa siempre la misma cantidad de espacios/tabuladores, SIEMPRE. En Python es OBLIGATORIO ser consistente con la indentación!

Answer (score 1):

Como te dije en el comentario, en Python la [indentación](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) (el sangrado de las líneas) es MUY importante, pues se encarga de definir los bloques de código. Tu código no tiene errores, excepto que lo has indentado como has querido sin seguir una estructura definida. Aquí tienes el mismo código pero correctamente indentado (y funcionando):

```
# Conversor de dolares
import math

opciones = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
while True:
    print(''' 
    Esto es un conversor de dolar 
    1.convertir dolar=>Euro
    2.convertir dolar=>Pesos colombianos
    3.convertir dolar=>Soles peruanos
    4.convertir dolar=>Libra esterlina
    5.convertir dolar=>Yenes
    6.Salir
    ''')
    opcion = input('Introducir opcion: ')
    if not (opcion in opciones):
        print('No seleccione ninguna opcion valida')
        input('pulse para continuar')
        continue
    if opcion == '1':
        try:
            dolar = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
            Euro = dolar * 0.85
            print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Euro")
            input('Pulse para continuar')
        except:
            print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
            continue
    if opcion == '2':
        try:
            dolar = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
            Euro = dolar * 3715.01
            print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Pesos colombianos")
            input('Pulse para continuar')
        except:
            print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
            continue
    if opcion == '3':
        try:
            dolar = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
            Euro = dolar * 3.55
            print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Soles peruanos")
            input('Pulse para continuar')
        except:
            print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
            continue
    if opcion == '4':
        try:
            dolar = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
            Euro = dolar * 0.75
            print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Libra esterlina")
            input('Pulse para continuar')
        except:
            print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
            continue
    if opcion == '5':
        try:
            dolar = float(input('Introduzca la cantidad de dolar: '))
            Euro = dolar * 0.0094
            print(round(dolar, 4), " son: ", round(Euro, 4), "Yenes")
            input('Pulse para continuar')
        except:
            print('Usted no ah intoducido in valor numerico ')
            continue
```

Fíjate cómo ahora todas las líneas que pertecen a un mismo bloque de código se encuentran a la misma altura.

Comment: Ok , Muchas gracias je jeje 

Comment: La mejor manera de agradecer es marcar como respuesta, así de paso otros usuarios pueden encontrar la respuesta correcta si tienen un problema parecido!